# How do I access / deploy / launch userapi for a deployed network on hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have deployed a business network using network admin card.Now I want to access the network using a user card (participant).Is there any command to access the existing deployed network as member(not as admin).

For Example : In composer playground there is access different participants(other than admins).
I need similar such access of participants for network deployed on hyper-ledger composer

Please share the commands for accessing the network from user identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Deployed the business network using the **PeerAdmin** card, and after that you start interacting with the business network using **Network Admin** with a card usually something like admin@demo-network.

In order to use different Participants, you need to Issue and Identity to the Participant, and then switch to that Identity.

In the Playground if you click on 'Admin' in the top right corner, you can go to the ID Registry and click the button `Issue New ID`.  When you have created the new Identity you will be able to hover over it in the ID Registry and click the `Use now` button.

It is also possible to Issue Identities using the CLI or REST API.

This extract from the Glossary of terms introduces Identities:

**Identity**: An identity is a distinct unique identifier associated with a participant. When joining a business network, an identity is issued to a participant which is used by the participant to interact with the business network. Identity documents normally expire after a given length of time, but can be issued or revoked maunally. Hyperledger Composer uses Hyperledger Fabric enrollment certificates as identity documents.
[Glossary](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/glossary)